# useEffect clean up previous data

Tags: reactjs, use-effect

**Hi** guys!
I'm using calendarific API to display data in a table. The issue here is that whenever a new search is submitted, the new data is rendered beside the old one and the clean up is not working out.
Menu component:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(() => ({
  root: {
    flexGrow: 1,
  },
}));

const Menu = () => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [hits, fetchData] = useHoliday("");
  const [holidayData, setHolidayData] = useState(null);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    setHolidayData(hits[0]);
    setLoading(true);
  }, [hits]);

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <Grid container>
        <Grid item xs={12}>
          <InputText onFormSubmit={fetchData} />
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={12}>
          {loading ? (
            <TableData holidayData={holidayData} />
          ) : (
            <div>Loading...</div>
          )}
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Menu;
```

Table component:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    width: "100%",
  },
  container: {
    maxHeight: 440,
  },
});

const columns = [
  { id: "name", label: "Name", minWidth: 170 },
  { id: "country", label: "Country", minWidth: 100 },
  { id: "description", label: "Description", minWidth: 170, align: "center" },
  { id: "type", label: "Type", align: "center", minWidth: 170 },
];

const TableData = ({ holidayData }) => {
  const classes = useStyles();

  if (!holidayData) return <></>;

  return (
    <Paper className={classes.root}>
      <TableContainer className={classes.container}>
        <Table>
          <TableHead>
            <TableRow>
              {columns.map((column) => (
                <TableCell
                  key={column.id}
                  align={column.align}
                  style={{ minWidth: column.minWidth }}
                >
                  {column.label}
                </TableCell>
              ))}
            </TableRow>
          </TableHead>
          <TableBody tabIndex={-1}>
            {holidayData !== undefined &&
              holidayData.map((place) => (
                <TableRow>
                  <TableCell key={place.description}>{place.name}</TableCell>
                  <TableCell key={place.description}>
                    {place.country.name}
                  </TableCell>
                  <TableCell key={place.description}>
                    {place.description}
                  </TableCell>
                  <TableCell key={place.description} align="center">
                    {place.type}
                  </TableCell>
                </TableRow>
              ))}
          </TableBody>
        </Table>
      </TableContainer>
    </Paper>
  );
};

export default TableData;
```

A custom hook for fetching data:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import calendarific from "../apis/calendarific";

const useHoliday = (defaultSearchTerm) => {
  const [hits, setHits] = useState([]);
  const [status, setStatus] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData(defaultSearchTerm);
    setStatus(true);
  }, [defaultSearchTerm]);

  const fetchData = async (term) => {
    const response = await calendarific.get("/holidays", {
      params: {
        country: term,
      },
    });
    let arrayHoliday = Object.values(response.data.response);
    setHits(arrayHoliday);
  };
  return [hits, fetchData];
};

export default useHoliday;
```

[an example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w4Ig5.png)

First search "France" and then "Mexico".

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`setHolidayData(hits[0])` looks fishy to me. Essentially whenever hits changes, you're setting some state with the first element of the hits array. Are you sure you want to be doing that?

Comment: What would you suggest to improve that? I made a `console.log(hits)` and it's an array with the data located in hits[0].

Comment: Solve it! it was an issue in the keys in Table component